# "I've just seen your message, it had been a while since you sent it."

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

> I've just seen your message, it had been a while since you sent it.

I wrote this sentence but I'm not sure if it is grammatically correct, because I started with present perfect then used past perfect.

I received a message month ago, and I'm trying to answer it now.

Is my sentence acceptable or there is a better way?

Comment: Can you tell us why you think the sentence is wrong? (The word _while_ is spelled incorrectly, but I don't think that is what you mean here.)

Comment: _Gramm**a**r_ is the correct spelling. Please tell us why do you think the grammar is wrong. If you haven't looked at them yet, please visit our [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. They explain how to write a question that we can answer.

Comment: I wrote this sentence and not sure if  the grammer is correct, because i started with present perfect then used past perfect

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information, and tell us what research you did. Why do you think the perfect is necessary here? (Use the `edit` link under your question.)

Comment: @safi Tell us _why_ you think you need to use the perfect here. What sources did you consult? Without more information, your question may be closed!

Comment: @P.E.Dant  ahh no, I have not consulted anyone, I wrote it in the perfect tense spontaneously!, and I just asking if its right  ?

Comment: It's neither "right" nor "wrong," but you don't need to use the past perfect at all. A native speaker would probably write: _I just saw your message, it's been been a while since you sent it._ Some wouldn't even use the _present perfect:_ _I just saw your message, you sent it a while ago._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When giving us context, you mention that the message was received *a month ago*. That's good. Include such temporal information in the sentence you're trying to construct, and allow those time phrases to guide your choice of tense. Do not rely only upon the tense to convey the temporal information.

> I have *just now* seen your message, which you sent *a month ago*.

The phrase *a month ago* establishes a discrete point-in-time in the past.  Thus, a simple past is suitable.

*Just now* means very recently, a few moments ago.  You're referring to a very recent event that colors your present circumstances. Thus, the present-perfect is suitable.

Let's imagine that you are a procrastinator.

> Last week I saw the message which you had sent three weeks earlier. I'm sorry
>   it has taken me so long to reply.